# How to filter Ansible's JSON output and compare with string?

Tags: json, ansible, jinja2, jsonresult

I am using the yum module in ansible to list all updates on a system. The output is something like this:

```
results: [
  {
    "name": "rubygem-ffi", 
    "nevra": "0:rubygem-ffi-1.9.10-2.el7.x86_64", 
    "repo": "epel", 
    "epoch": "0", 
    "version": "1.9.10", 
    "release": "2.el7", 
    "yumstate": "available", 
    "arch": "x86_64"
  }
  {
    "name": "some-package", 
    "nevra": "blah", 
    "repo": "epel", 
    "epoch": "0", 
    "version": "6", 
    "release": "6.el7", 
    "yumstate": "available", 
    "arch": "x86_64"
  }
]
```

And the code I use in tasks is:

```
  - name: yum list
    yum: list=updates
    register: output
```

What I want is to print a debug message only when the name of a package is found in the JSON output. Like this:

```
  - debug: msg="Found it!"
    when: [output.I don't know the right filter] == "rubygem-ffi"
```

I tried something like `output.results.name` or `output.results|map(attribute='name')|list` but they don't seem to work

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be other solutions. This one works for me:

```
  - debug: msg='Found It!'
    when: item.name == 'rubygem-ffi'
    with_items: output.results
```